# ios bold a text with custom font name that has a space in it

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont

i am able to add a custom font, called "jelly beans.ttf"

i am able to add this front to my application, and when i set a uilabel font to it, it works, it displays the custom font.

however, now i need to make the text bold with this custom font, after some research
it seems i just need to do append -Bold at the end, like so

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"jelly beans-Bold" size:30];
```

the following line works, but text not getting bold

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"jellyh beans" size:30];
```

but it doesn't work

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think with ttf you can't have multiple font weights. Basically you need to import another ttf font that is 'jelly beans bold'. If you need to use both bold and regular then you need two ttfs.

hope this helps.